# Bin/Bash script to rename directory folder unique names

Tags: bash, ubuntu, rename

I'm learning about the rename function in Bin/Bash and I have two goals that I would like to script.

1. I have 500 unique folder names of various company names that need to be updated. I have the information currently in a excel document with column A = OldName and column B = NewName. I'd like to run a script to reference any name found in Column A to be replaced with matching Column B in the same row.
2. Then under each of these folder directories, I have to do the same thing.

I've looked into the rename [1] function on ubuntu linux VM but the common scripts I found were the following:

```
cd yourDir
find . -type d -name "*test*" | while read f; do mv $f $(echo $f | sed 's/test/demo/'); done
find . -type f -name "*test*" | while read f; do mv $f $(echo $f | sed 's/test/demo/'); done
```

These type of scripts replace "X" value with "Y", rather I'd like to match specific names from Column A and replaced with Column B.

Thanks!

Tested out the Ubuntu Rename function as below:

```
cd yourDir
find . -type d -name "*test*" | while read f; do mv $f $(echo $f | sed 's/test/demo/'); done
find . -type f -name "*test*" | while read f; do mv $f $(echo $f | sed 's/test/demo/'); done
```

However, this doesn't accomplish what I'm trying to do as each name is specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do all this with the `find` from the GNU `findutils`, a `bash` associative array (recent enough `bash` only) and a `bash` function.

First use any excel processor (e.g., `incsv` and `csvcut`) to extract your old and new names from your file and store them in an associative array. As you do not give the details about this excel file let us assume that you know how to do this and that `arr[old]=new` is already defined. The following assumes that you want to rename directories `a`, `b` and `c` in `1`, `2` and `3`, respectively. So we declare:

```
$ declare -A arr=(["a"]="1" ["b"]="2" ["c"]="3")
```

Next, as array bash variables cannot be exported let us export a function that does the renaming and use the evil `eval` to declare it with the internal declaration of the associative array:

```
$ eval '
foo() {
  '"$(declare -p arr)"'
  p="${1%/*}"
  d="${1##*/}"
  [[ -v arr["$d"] ]] && echo mv "$1" "$p/${arr[$d]}"
}'
$ export -f foo
```

And finally let us use it with `find` on a little demo:

```
$ mkdir -p {a..c}/{a..c}/{a..c}
$ find . -depth -type d -exec bash -c 'foo "$1"' _ {} \;
mv ./b/b/b ./b/b/2
mv ./b/b/c ./b/b/3
mv ./b/b/a ./b/b/1
mv ./b/b ./b/2
...
mv ./a/a/b ./a/a/2
mv ./a/a/c ./a/a/3
mv ./a/a/a ./a/a/1
mv ./a/a ./a/1
mv ./a ./1
```

If it looks OK remove the `echo` on front of the `mv` command in the declaration of `foo`.

Note: `-depth` is needed in order to rename the leaves first. The quoting of the function declaration uses a mixture of double and single quotes, it is needed to incorporate the declaration of the `arr` associative array.